# FCM notification not work in OREO

Tags: firebase, push-notification, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I have send fcm notification my Backend to my all app user . Bt notification not send in Android OREO version all other version notification working

Comment: @JonasLochmann ok

Comment: It's hard to tell anything if you don't provide us at least the code you currently have. Please provide as much details as possible. For your scenario, it's probable that you don't have Notification Channels implemented.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding Notification channels for your messages?

See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications#ManageChannels
for more help.

"Starting in Android 8.0 (API level 26), all notifications must be assigned to a channel or it will not appear."